# Could not find function in R?

Tags: r, function

I am getting the error:
Error: could not find function "rlm"
where rlm
Why isn't R working for certain functions?
I wrote

> fit<-rlm(z~cbind(time(z),time(z)^2))
>   Error: could not find function "rlm"

where z is the time series.

Typing ?rlm takes me to the robust fitting of linear models page, but im still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

You must load a library called MASS using library(MASS) before writing your code-line.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to reply just to thank. But you actually saved my life. thank you so much.